# Extract content of <a> tag

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have written code to extract the url and title of a book using `BeautifulSoup` from a page.

But it is not extracting the name of the book *Astounding Stories of Super-Science April 1930* between `>` and `</a>` tags.

How can I extract the name of the book?

I have tried the `findnext` method recommended in another question, but I get an `AttributeError` on that.

HTML:

```
    <li>
        <a class="extiw" href="//www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/29390" title="ebook:29390">Astounding Stories of Super-Science April 1930</a>
        <a class="image" href="/wiki/File:BookIcon.png"><img alt="BookIcon.png" height="16" src="//www.gutenberg.org/w/images/9/92/BookIcon.png" width="16"/></a>
        (English)
    </li>
```

Code below:

```
def make_soup(BASE_URL):
    r = requests.get(BASE_URL, verify = False)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    return soup

def extract_text_urls(html):
    soup = make_soup(BASE_URL)

    for li in soup.findAll('li'):
        try:
            try:
                print li.a['href'], li.a['title']
                print "\n"
            except KeyError:
                pass
        except TypeError:
            pass

extract_text_urls(filename)
```

Comment: Please link the page you are trying to scrape.

Comment: Also it's unclear what "the findnext method" is.

Comment: the page i am trying to scrape is: https://www.gutenberg.org/wiki/Science_Fiction_(Bookshelf)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the `text` attribute of the element. The following works for me:

```
def make_soup(BASE_URL):
    r = requests.get(BASE_URL)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    return soup

def extract_text_urls(html):
    soup = make_soup(BASE_URL)

    for li in soup.findAll('li'):
        try:
            try:
                print li.a['href'], li.a.text
                print "\n"
            except KeyError:
                pass
        except TypeError:
            pass

extract_text_urls('http://www.gutenberg.org/wiki/Science_Fiction_(Bookshelf)')
```

I get the following output for the element in question

`//www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/29390 Astounding Stories of Super-Science April 1930`

Answer (score 3):

According to [the  BeautifulSoup documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#string) the `.string` property should accomplish what you are trying to do, by editing your original listing this way:

```
    # ... 
        try:
            print li.a['href'], li.a['title']
            print "\n"
            print li.a.string
        except KeyError:
            pass
    # ...
```

You probably want to surround it with something like

```
if li.a['class'] == "extiw":
    print li.a.string
```

since, in your example, only the anchors of class `extiw` contain a book title.

Thanks @wilbur for pointing out the optimal solution.

Comment: This may work, but I think the best practice is to use the `.text` attribute as I've described in my answer below

Comment: @wilbur: it certainly looks better, thank you. However, the BS4 documentation I've linked doesn't mention that. Where did you find it? On a closer inspection, it does mention [`.string`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#string), could it be the *best* practice?

Comment: I've been using `.text` for a while, I think I must've read about it in a version before bs4?

Comment: It does look like `.string` is more robust. It seems like it includes things like newlines where `.text` may not always?

Answer (score 1):

I did not see how you can extract the text within the  tag. I would do something like this:

```
from bs4 import BeatifulSoup as bs
from urllib2 import urlopen as uo
soup = bs(uo(html))

for li in soup.findall('li'):
    a = li.find('a')
    book_title = a.contents[0]
    print book_title
```

Answer (score 1):

To get just the text that is not inside any tags use the `get_text()` method.  It is in the documentation [here](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text).

I can't test it because I don't know the url of the page you are trying to scrape, but you can probably just do it with the `li` tag since there doesn't seem to be any other text.

Try replacing this:

```
    for li in soup.findAll('li'):
    try:
        try:
            print li.a['href'], li.a['title']
            print "\n"
        except KeyError:
            pass
    except TypeError:
        pass
```

with this:

```
    for li in soup.findAll('li'):
    try:
        print(li.get_text())
        print("\n")
    except TypeError:
        pass
```